# Sort list of list in prolog?

Tags: sorting, prolog, swi-prolog

In SWI-Prolog there is the predicate [sort/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2) to sort lists.
Is there a good way to sort a list of list with fixed length by some index. I mean in example, if I have the following list of elements

- `[[1,2], [3,1], [2, 5]]`

Is there a function in SWI-Prolog to sort it by first or second index. By first index the result would be:

- `[[1,2], [2,5], [3, 1]]`

By second index:

- `[[3,1], [1,2], [2, 5]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3 if removing duplicates is OK:

```
test(Nth1, S) :-
    L = [[1,2], [3,1], [2, 5], [1,2]],
    predsort(nth1_compare(Nth1), L, S).
    
nth1_compare(Nth1, Comp, L1, L2) :-
    nth1(Nth1, L1, V1),
    nth1(Nth1, L2, V2),
    compare(Comp, V1, V2).
```

Results:

```
?- test(1, S).
S = [[1,2],[2,5],[3,1]].

?- test(2, S).
S = [[3,1],[1,2],[2,5]].
```

Answer (score 2):

The efficient *and* portable way to get what you want goes like this:

1. map each element `X` of the original list to a pair `I-X`, where `I` is the value to sort by.
2. use `keysort/2` on the resulting list; note that `keysort/2`  preserves duplicate items.
3. at last, get rid of the values of `I` in the sorted list—we don't need them anymore.

The above directly translates to the predicate `lists_sortedBySecondItem/2`:

```
lists_sortedBySecondItem(Ess,Xss) :-
   maplist(list_pair,Ess,Pairs),             % (1)
   keysort(Pairs,Sorted),                    % (2)
   maplist(pair_second,Sorted,Xss).          % (3)

list_pair(Xs,I-Xs) :-
   nth(2,Xs,I).

pair_second(_-X,X).
```

Sample query using GNU Prolog 1.5.0:

```
| ?- lists_sortedBySecondItem([[1,2],[3,1],[2,5]], Xss).

Xss = [[3,1],[1,2],[2,5]]

yes
```